# Smartsheet- List collaborators of a sheet

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

After reading the documentation I dint find any api to get list of collaborators(the users the sheet is shared with)  apart from the detail of the sheet's owner.

If I miss out on some api, do point out ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of collaborators for a Sheet (i.e., the people with whom the Sheet is shared) by using the [List Sheet Shares](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-sheet-shares) operation.

`GET /sheets/{sheetId}/shares`

Here's an example of using the [Java SDK (v2)](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-java-sdk) to List Sheet Shares:

```
// List sheet shares (specify 'includeAll' parameter with value of "true").

PaginationParameters parameters = new PaginationParameters.PaginationParametersBuilder().setIncludeAll(true).build();

smartsheet.sheetResources().shareResources().listShares(sheetId, parameters);
```